# Is there some performance issue If i set bigint unsigned as primary key of a myisam table on mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know also, if i should use varchar or bigint as primary key to store big IDS with about 11-15 digits, which them has better performance?

thanks.

Comment: I haven't measured, but I'd say a bigint is a better design decision than varchar(15)

Answer (score 0):

## bigint

bigint is 8 bytes
varchar is ~13 bytes

Ints are also faster than a string of characters.
Plus varchar is considered a dynamic field, and you can get a pretty big performance boost if you keep all your fields static.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot actually. Using INT rather then BIGINT can make a significant reduction in disk space. Just this one change alone can save you 10%-20% (depends on your particular situation). More significantly, when used as a primary key, and for foreign keys and indexes, reducing your index size could be 50%, and this will improve performance when these indexes are used.

Read Here : http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=13825

Answer (score 0):

One more thing against string pk - if you use INNODB engine, PK also defines the physical order of the row (clustered key), so even `insert` will have more overhead and fragmentation if row inserted is out of the order. With numbers you can have auto_increment column, so each number will be greater than previous...